# Rendering with Neo4j Spatial as backend

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

Since one can import .osm files into [Neo4j Spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) the next natural question is: Does a renderer (like [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/)) exist that reads from [Neo4j Spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) (like Mapnik does from [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/))?

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll to the bottom of that GitHub Link, you'll see there's some support in [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/).

This [Neo4j Spatial in GeoServer](http://oss.infoscience.co.jp/neo4j/wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_Spatial_in_GeoServer.html) page gives an idea of what it looks like in GeoServer.

However that page is 6 years old - the last update on the readme.md on the GitHub page is fairly recent so I suggest you use that instead :)

Not familiar with Neo4J so not tried this myself. Configuring it seems to involve copying the Neo4J Spatial JARs into your GeoServer install.